# check whether a variable is in increasing order in R

Tags: r, sorting

Supposing I have a variable

```
x <- c(1,3,5,7,8)
```

Now `x` is in increasing order

How to check whether a variable is in increasing order in R?

Comment: Perhaps, would negating `is.unsorted` work here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From `?is.unsorted`:

> Test if an object is not sorted (in increasing order) ...

So, in this case, you could:

```
is.sorted = Negate(is.unsorted)
is.sorted(x)
#[1] TRUE
#> is.sorted(1:5)
#[1] TRUE
#> is.sorted(5:1)
#[1] FALSE
#> is.sorted(sample(5))
#[1] FALSE
#> is.sorted(sort(runif(5)))
#[1] TRUE
#> is.sorted(c(1,2,2,3))
#[1] TRUE
#> is.sorted(c(1,2,2,3), strictly = T)
#[1] FALSE
```

This function is fast, because it loops over the vector and breaks the loop as soon as an element is not ">=" (or ">", if "strictly = T") from the previous one.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
all(diff(x) > 0)
```

or

```
all(diff(x) >= 0)
```

I agree with @flodel that `is.unsorted` (h/t @alexis_laz) is probably even better.

Comment: +1 - you can also do `all(tail(x, -1) > head(x, -1))`. It is more typing but it is faster as it avoids computing the difference.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the differences:

```
R> x <- c(1,3,5,7,8) 
R> allIncreasing <- function(x) all(diff(x)>0)
R> allIncreasing(x)
[1] TRUE
R> y <- x; y[3] <-0 
R> allIncreasing(y)
[1] FALSE
R>
```